# Google extension popup not showing up

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, manifest

```
{
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Bot 2.0",
    "default_icon": "logo.png",
    "default_popup": "view/options.html"
```

I've been trying to make the popup feature to be activated, but every time I click on it nothing happens. Did I miss anything?

Comment: try "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": {
         "38": "icon38by38pixels.png"
      },
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
   },

Comment: Still doesn't work, not sure what exactly is wrong with my extension. @MarcGuiselin

Comment: Here is my full manifest http://pastebin.com/KD7wrXue @MarcGuiselin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `manifest.json` file, you're writing 2 times `browser_action` property:

```
{
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Bot 2.0",
        "default_icon": { "38": "icon38by38pixels.png" },
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
   .....
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "logo.png"
   },
   .....
}
```

You need to write the `browser_action` only once in the `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Bot 2.0",
        "default_icon": "logo.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
   "background": {
      "persistent": false,
      "scripts": [ "view/jquery-1.9.1.min.js", "background.js" ]
   },
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "view/jquery-1.9.1.min.js", "supreme.js" ],
      "matches": [ "*://*.supremenewyork.com/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
   }, {
      "js": [ "view/jquery-1.9.1.min.js", "checkout.js" ],
      "matches": [ "*://*.supremenewyork.com/checkout/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
   } ],
   "description": "X",
   "icons": {
      "128": "logo.png",
      "16": "logo.png",
      "48": "logo.png"
   },
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Bot 2.0",
   "options_page": "view/options.html",
   "permissions": [ "tabs", "*://*.supremenewyork.com/*" ],
   "version": "1.0",
   "web_accessible_resources": [ "view/jquery.min.map" ]
}
```